# QUnit and Context

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

Trying to use QUnit's context passing (http://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit/module), which initially works, but seems to be completely inconsistent with sub-modules.

Running the below a test, or module, after a sub-module seems to wipe the context.

```js
QUnit.module('TEST #1', { 
  before: function() { 
    console.log('Test #1 - before: ', this); 
    this.abc = 123; 
  }
}, function() {
  // Run the top level test
  QUnit.test('Test A', function() {
    console.log("test A: ", this);
  });
    
  QUnit.test('Test B', function() {
    console.log("test B: ", this);
  });
    
  QUnit.test('Test C', function() {
    console.log("test C: ", this);
  });
});

QUnit.module('TEST #2', { 
  before: function() { 
    console.log('Test #2 - before: ', this); 
    this.abc = 123; 
  }
}, function() {
  // Defining a sub module
  QUnit.module('SUB-TEST', { 
    before: function() { 
      console.log('Test #2 - before (subtest): ', this);
      this.more = 456; 
    }
  }, function(t1) {
    // Run the second level test
    QUnit.test('SubTest', function() {
      console.log("subtest: ", this);
    });
  });
  
  // Run the top level test
  QUnit.test('Test', function() {
    // This is where 'this' is empty!!
    console.error("test (FAULTY HERE): ", this);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qunit/2.4.1/qunit.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qunit/2.4.1/qunit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Am I missing something, or is this a bug?